# How to sort API response for some field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just start to learn Reactjs and have stopped with some question. 
I've fetched data through axios for some API endpoint(get countries with some data like population,currencies,region etc.) and I want to sort data for some field(region or population for example).

I thought that in reactjs it will be simple to do and reactjs have some built-in things to do that. But when I've tried to do that and when I've searched answer in google I was really exposed. What is the best way to implement sorting? How can I do that?

What I've tried:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state={
          countries:[],

      }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      axios.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
      .then(response => {
          this.setState({

              countries:response.data

          })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log("error", error)
      })
  }

  render(){
      return(

          <div className = 'table'>

          <table>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
          <th>Country name </th>
          <th>Currencies</th>
          <th>Region </th>
          <th>Flag </th>
          <th >Population</th>
          <th>Languages</th>

          </tr>
          {
             this.state.countries.map((country,id) => {
                  return(

                      <tr className="tableRow">
                     <td> {country.name}</td>
                     <td>{country.currencies.map((currency,i)=>{
                     return (

                     <p>
                         <span>{currency.name} </span>

                         <span>{currency.symbol} </span>
                         </p>

                     )
                     })} </td>
                     <td> {country.region}</td>
                     <td> <img src={country.flag} alt={country.denonym}/> </td>
                     <td> {country.population} </td>
                     <td> {country.languages.map((language)=>{
                     return (
                         <span> {language.name} </span>
                     )
                     })} </td>
                      </tr>


                  )

              })

          }
          </tbody>

          </table>
          </div>

      )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: how are you trying to sort them? alphabetically?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do is something like this:

```
...
this.state.countries.sort(/* Provide sort function here */).map((country,id) => {
...
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: sorry but maybe I've asked my question wrong but I need sort data for one field population when I click for it. Like for many sites: click-sorting asc, click-sorting-desc. How can I implement this?